# Inneficient loading of lot of small files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble loading a lot of small image files (aprox. 90k png images) into a single 3D `np.array`.
The current solution takes couple of hours which is unacceptable.

The images are size 64x128.

I have a `pd.DataFrame` called `labels` with the names of the images and want to import whose images in the same order as in the `labels` variable.

My current solution is:

```py
dataset = np.empty([1, 64, 128], dtype=np.int32)

for file_name in labels['file_name']:
    array = cv.imread(f'{IMAGES_PATH}/{file_name}.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    dataset = np.append(dataset, [array[:]], axis=0)
```

From what I have timed, the most time consuming operation is the `dataset = np.append(dataset, [array[:]], axis=0)`, which takes around 0.4s per image.

Is there any better way to import such files and store them in a `np.array`?

I was thinking about multiprocessing, but I want the `labels` and `dataset` to be in the same order.

Comment: How about importing them into numpy array and saving the array? Also, you can have ordered results with  multiprocessing or concurrent.futures, however, the runtime on this is probably defined by the disk speed.

Comment: If you know you have 90,000 images you can surely declare your array with size `[90000, 64, 128]` up-front rather than appending and reallocating 90,000 times?

Comment: load them into an array (or a group of arrays) and save them binary (using .npy or .npz for a case of multiple arrays) and then load them. If they all cannot fit into your memory at once, use memmap in numpy to access pieces of them at a time.

Comment: list append is faster.  Make the big array from the list at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game developers typically concatenate bunches of small images into a single big file and then use sizes and offsets to slice out the currently needed piece. Here's example of how this can be done with [imagemagick](https://www.tombraiderforums.com/showthread.php?p=8282273):

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x *.png out.png
```

But then again it will not get around the reading of 90k of small files. And magick has it's own peculiarities which may or may not surface in your case.

Also, I haven't originally noticed that you are having problem with `np.append(dataset, [array[:]], axis=0)`.
That is very bad line. Appending in a loop is never a performant code.

Either preallocate the array and write to it. Or use numpy's functions for concatenating many arrays at [once](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
dataset = np.empty([int(90e3), 64, 128], dtype=np.int32)
for i,file_name in enumerate(labels['file_name']):
    array = cv.imread(f'{IMAGES_PATH}/{file_name}.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    dataset[i,:,:] = array
```